# Interface and Abstract Class Aggregation in UML

Tags: java, interface, uml, abstract-class

I was given an assignment in which i have to implement an applet that simulates a solar system that has a sun with planets orbiting, and the planets must have moons orbiting the planets. I have successfully implemented the animations, but in order to receive full credit we need to use the following UML: 
[image: The UML given by the teacher]

I understand that the framework has an instance of `Sun`, and `Sun` implements the methods in the interface `Orbit` and has an instance of `OrbitingBody` created with a `Planet` constructor, and so on... What i don't undesrtand is the relation in the UML between the interface `Orbit` and the abstract class `OrbitingBody`.

```
/****************************************************************/
import java.awt.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Sun implements Orbit {
    private Dimension dim;
    private OrbitingBody earth;
    private OrbitingBody mars;
    //Other vars

    public void init(Dimension dim) {
        // CODE irrelevant for the question
    }

    public void setPlanetPosition() {
        // CODE irrelevant for the question
    }

    public int calX(int distance, int angle){
        // CODE irrelevant for the question
    }
    public int calY(int distance, int angle){
       // CODE irrelevant for the question
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        // CODE irrelevant for the question
    }
}


/****************************************************************/
import java.awt.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Planet extends OrbitingBody implements Orbit {
    private Moon moon;
    private Moon eris;


    Planet(int x, int y, Color color) {
        super.x = x;
        super.y = y;
        moon = new Moon();
        eris = new Moon();
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int calX(int distance, int angle){
        // CODE irrelevant for the question
    }
    public int calY(int distance, int angle){
        // CODE irrelevant for the question
    }
}



/****************************************************************/
  public interface Orbit {
    int calX(int distance, int angle);
    int calY(int distance, int angle);
}



/****************************************************************/
   import java.awt.*;

public abstract class OrbitingBody {
    protected Color color;
    protected int x, y;
    protected int radius = 25;

    void setPosition(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        // CODE irrelevant for the question
    }
}
```

Comment: [questions not to be asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Add your code , what have you tried.

Comment: Under standard assumptions in astrodynamics the barycenter of the two bodies is a focus of both orbits. Pertaining to astronomy, an orbiting body (sometimes seen as OB) is any object smaller than the body it orbits. These may include, but are not limited to, comets, planets, dwarf planets, moons, and asteroids. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbiting_body so moon orbits earth and is smaller than earth, which means moon is an orbiting body in relate to earth. Same goes earth orbits sun, and is smaller than sun, in which case earth is an orbiting body for sun, got it?

Comment: I understand everything from my homework, functionality wise is completed, the part i am having trouble is implementing the design of the UML **ONLY** implemneting the relation deacribes by the Interface `Orbit` and the Abstract Class `OrbitingBody`. that is the only par where I need clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can understand your confusion.

I'm having trouble understanding the purpose of the UML diagram myself (and I do that for a living).

#### Issues with the UML diagram

- Usage of **aggregation** (open diamond at the end of the associations) for each association. The aggregation indicates a whole part relationship. I don't see that in any of the associations on the diagram. How is a `Planet` part of a `Sun`, or a `Moon` part of a `Planet`?
- The UML notations for `«Orbit»` and `{Orbiting Body}` are wrong. I'm guessing the `Orbit` is meant to be an Interface? In that case the correct notation would be to either use a lollipop notation, or a standard box with the keyword «interface» before the name. As for `Orbiting Body`, the braces are only used in UML to indicate constraints. I'm guessing again that your teacher meant to indicate an **abstract** class? In that case the correct would be to use italics for the name, so *Orbiting Body*
- The aggregation between 'Orbiting Body' and 'Orbit' does not make any sense. As it is written now an `Orbit` is part of an `Orbiting Body`. I could understand if there were a normal association between `Orbiting Body` and `Orbit`
- The direction of the association between 'Orbiting Body `and 'Orbit` is the reverse of the associations between `Sun` and and `Planet` and `Planet` and `Moon`. I would think the associations between the classes implementing `Orbit` and `Orbiting Body` would be some kind of redefinition of that association, but in that case the direction would need to be the same. (and the redefinition would need to be indicated as well).
  As it is designed now there should be two associations you would need to implement to associations between `Sun` and `Planet` and between `Planet` and `Moon`. One in each direction.

I would suggest you ignore the details of the actual UML diagram because of it's inconsistencies and use your own judgement. A programmer should be more then a mindless codemonkey translating UML in code. You should think for yourself and (if possible) challenge and/or improve the analysis.

#### Issues in your code:

- Think about how to implement the relation between Orbiting Bodies (`Planet`, `Moon`) and Orbits (`Sun`, `Planet`).

  - In which direction do you need that?
  - Do you need it at the general level or only at the concrete level
- Why do you have two attributes of type `Moon` on your `Planet` class?. Can't a `Planet` have more then 2 `Moon`s? I would expect some kind of list of `Moon`s
- Same comment for your `Sun` class with regards to `Planet`.

Comment: Geert, while I agree with most of your concerns, the hollow diamond as per UML specification "Indicates that the Property has shared aggregation semantics. Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler." (p. 110).

Comment: @ThomasKilian I know, but we all know that as Aggregation, and the common use is that it indicates a whole-part relationship. One paragraph above your qoute it says: *Sometimes a Property is used to model circumstances in which one instance is used to group together a set of instances;
this is called aggregation. To represent such circumstances, a Property has an aggregation property, of type
AggregationKind;*

Comment: Which is meant for the "aggregation of shared and composite" (pun intended).

Comment: Most likely (since the diagram is erroneous anyway) they need to be filled diamonds. A planet is only a planet with its sun and a moon only a moon with its planet. Without they are just stone bricks.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I think they should just be plain association (AggregationKind = none). I don't see any type of whole/part relation (shared or composite) between the sun and it's planets, or between a planet and it's moons.

Comment: Well, no! The Earth is only a planet with Sun. Else it's only a lump of stone and no longer a planet!

Comment: @GeertBellekens Thanks for your time, I did implement all those relations between sun and planet, and planet and moon. I did only 2 declarations of each class just for the sake of testing my code. I refactored some more code into my abstract class, and made the sun into a singleton. Now im working to implement the multiplicity of planets and moons :)

Comment: The singleton might work in our solar system, but not for binary solar systems ;)